# Where is Shared Libraries located in AOSP?

Tags: java, android, android-source

I need to know where will Shared Libraries located in aosp because in Android.mk file, I have libnfc_tf_jni

```
LOCAL_JNI_SHARED_LIBRARIES := libnfc_tf_jni
```

When I use mm command,  it throws an error that

```
'out/host/linux-x86/bin/aapt', needed by 'out/target/product/sabresd_6dq/obj/APPS/Nfc_intermediates/package.apk', missing and no known rule to make it
```

Edited by adding Android.mk file:

```
LOCAL_PATH:= $(call my-dir)

########################################
# NCI Configuration
########################################
include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE_TAGS := optional
LOCAL_PRIVATE_PLATFORM_APIS := true
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := \
        $(call all-java-files-under, src)

LOCAL_SRC_FILES += \
        $(call all-java-files-under, tf)

LOCAL_PACKAGE_NAME := Nfc
LOCAL_CERTIFICATE := platform
LOCAL_STATIC_JAVA_LIBRARIES := NfcLogTags

LOCAL_JNI_SHARED_LIBRARIES := libnfc_tf_jni

LOCAL_PROGUARD_ENABLED := disabled

include $(BUILD_PACKAGE)

#####
# static lib for the log tags
#####
include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE_TAGS := optional

LOCAL_SRC_FILES := src/com/android/nfc/EventLogTags.logtags

LOCAL_MODULE:= NfcLogTags

include $(BUILD_STATIC_JAVA_LIBRARY)


include $(call all-makefiles-under,$(LOCAL_PATH))
```

**libnfc-tf/Android.mk::**

```
 LOCAL_PATH:= $(call my-dir)

# libnfc_tf

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_PRELINK_MODULE := false
LOCAL_ARM_MODE := arm

#phLibNfc
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := src/libnfc_tf.c
LOCAL_SRC_FILES += src/libnfc_tf_if.c
LOCAL_SRC_FILES += src/libnfc_tf_poll.c
LOCAL_SRC_FILES += src/libnfc_tf_hal.c
LOCAL_SRC_FILES += src/libnfc_tf_llcp.c
LOCAL_SRC_FILES += src/libnfc_tf_secure.c

LOCAL_CFLAGS += -DANDROID -pipe -fomit-frame-pointer -Wall -Wno-trigraphs -Werror-implicit-function-declaration  -fno-strict-aliasing -mapcs -mno-sched-prolog -mabi=aapcs-linux -mno-thumb-interwork -msoft-float -Uarm -fno-common -fpic

#debug option
#LOCAL_CFLAGS += -DDEBUG -D_DEBUG -DNFC_TF_DEBUG
#release option
#LOCAL_CFLAGS += -DNDEBUG

#includes
LOCAL_CFLAGS += -I$(LOCAL_PATH)/inc
#LOCAL_CFLAGS += -I$(LOCAL_PATH)/src

LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := external/openssl/include

LOCAL_MODULE:= libnfc_tf
LOCAL_MODULE_TAGS := optional
LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := libcutils libdl liblog libcrypto

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Comment: Have you created a module named "libnfc_tf_jni"? Can you paste your entire Android.mk?

Comment: Why are you looking for the location of shared libraries? The error messages looks like the `aapt` binary is missing. Run `m aapt` to build it.

Comment: After running, I am getting error as : 'out/target/product/sabresd_6dq/obj/SHARED_LIBRARIES/libnfc_tf_intermediates/link_type', needed by 'out/target/product/sabresd_6dq/obj/SHARED_LIBRARIES/libnfc_tf_jni_intermediates/link_type', missing and no known rule to make it
16:59:39 ninja failed with: exit status 1 @Simpl

Comment: @GilCol I added mk file

Comment: @Shadow Do you have the Android.mk for libnfc_tf_jni?

Comment: There is a folder called as external -> libnfc-tf-> Android.mk which is available.Actually I copied this folder "libnfc-tf" from 6 to Android 9.